# Does $\mathbb{R}$ possess any proper subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

> True / False: There are no proper subspaces of $\mathbb{R}$.

A proper subspace means that we are not counting $U = \{0\}$ and $V = \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, I said True since we need the existence of a $0$ vector to confirm the Axiom 4 which will tell if the vector is in the subspace.

However, I am not sure if that counts as a counterexample.

Comment: Well, you raise a good question. If you say you're not counting the zero subspace as proper, then it can't be a counterexample. When we talk about proper *subsets* we exclude the whole set and *the empty set*. The subspace $\{0\}$ is not the empty set.

Comment: It depends on the scalar field you are considering with $\mathbb R$

Comment: What is "Axiom 4"?  Different texts likely label the axioms differently (or may use different axioms entirely).

Comment: The axiom 4 is 0+u=u+0=u

Comment: @TedShifrin Just for completeness, some people use "proper subset" to mean "subset but not equal", i.e. the subset is allowed to be empty (unless the whole set is empty). Both conventions are relatively common in my experience.

Comment: I think most mathematicians refer to $\{0\}$ and the entire vector space as *trivial subspaces*, and so the question would be whether $\Bbb R$ has any nontrivial subspaces.

Answer (score 1):

Assume there is a proper $\Bbb R$-linear subspace of $\Bbb R$. It must contain some nonzero vector $v$. Now since it is closed under multiplication with values of $\Bbb R$ we find that for any $t\in \Bbb R$ the product $\frac{t}{v}\cdot v=t$ demonstrates that $t$ is contained in it as well. A contradiction.

Basically the same proof shows the more general fact, that a field (ie. a ring in which every nonzero element has a multiplicative inverse) has no nontrivial linear subspaces, which in this context are called *ideals*.